# Woocommerce: Different order_id for same products in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce plugin with WP and when I add to cart an item and then I add to cart the same item again, at the cart page it's displayed as one item with quantity of two and with one order_id. What I want is to be able to add to cart multiple times the same product and each product to get a unique order_id. Is there a way to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function bbloomer_split_product_individual_cart_items( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){

  $unique_cart_item_key = uniqid();

  $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_cart_item_key;

  return $cart_item_data;

}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'bbloomer_split_product_individual_cart_items', 10, 2 );


 

//add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', '__return_true' );

 

 

 

#***************************************************

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'mai_split_multiple_quantity_products_to_separate_cart_items', 10, 6 );

function mai_split_multiple_quantity_products_to_separate_cart_items( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {

 

    // If product has more than 1 quantity

    if ( $quantity > 1 ) {

 

        // Keep the product but set its quantity to 1

        WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, 1 );

 

        // Run a loop 1 less than the total quantity

        for ( $i = 1; $i <= $quantity -1; $i++ ) {

            /**

             * Set a unique key.

             * This is what actually forces the product into its own cart line item

             */

            $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() . "Hi Mom!" );

 

            // Add the product as a new line item with the same variations that were passed

            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data );

        }

 

    } 

 

}
```